# In Gson, how to detect type mismatch during deserialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

`gson.fromJson(json, type)` converts json to the class object. Suppose I have the json data that looks like

```
{
  "randomTiles": "true",
  "randomNumbers": "false",
  "randomPorts": "false",
  "name": "test"
}
```

and the class the json deserializes to that is defined as

```
public class CreateGameRequest {
    public String name;
    public boolean randomTiles;
    public boolean randomNumbers;
    public boolean randomPorts;
}
```

when I call

```
gson.fromJson(json, type)
```

then it should parse the json data and convert it to a `CreateGameRequest` object. Now the problem is suppose the data isn't well typed so it looks something like

```
{
  "randomTiles": "asdasd",
  "randomNumbers": "zxczxc",
  "randomPorts": "asdzxc",
  "name": "test"
}
```

now when calling json.fromJson() or in other words when deserializing to the above class object, Gson silently thinks "asdasd" is "false" without throwing exception for type mismatch. I noticed that `.fromJson()` throws `JsonSyntaxException` but that exception is only thrown suppose if i have a number without quote in the `boolean` fields in json object but doesn't seem to detect a text other than "true" "false" in `boolean` fields of the json object..do you know how can I detect if the json object has strings other than "true" "false" in `boolean` fields? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson tries its best to convert JSON values to a `boolean` value, considering most everything as false-y. I believe it uses `Boolean.valueOf(String)` to make the conversion.

You can be more strict by registering your own deserializer

```
class JsonBooleanDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            String value = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
            if ("true".equals(value) || "false".equals(value)) {
                return Boolean.valueOf(value);
            } else {
                throw new JsonParseException("Cannot parse json '" + json.toString() + "' to boolean value");
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Cannot parse json '" + json.toString() + "' to boolean value", e);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, deserializer)
    .registerTypeAdapter(boolean.class, deserializer)
    .create();
```